# I'm not getting value of cron to set in node-cron

Tags: node.js, node-cron

Let's say we have one event organized on 1st of march at 6.30 PM. So, what will be the cron stars(*) value if I have to schedule to send email 15 min earlier before getting event start??

Comment: Where's your code? What is the error? Please follow the [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.